# Categorizing Wikidata Items as a "place"

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm a little stuck on if a SPARQL query is possible for what I want to do:

I get that

> ?human wdt:P31 wd:Q5

would give me all items that are an instance of human.

Is there a similar way to find all items that are an instance of a place (e.g., town, city, country, river, continent, museum, building, etc.)?

Comment: yes, by just using the corresponding Wikidata concept ID

Comment: Thanks Stanislav!  Could you give a simple SPARQL example?  Cant find examples of "Wikidata Concept ID" in Google.

Answer (score 1):

The trick will likely be to find Wikidata class which is a good proxy for what you consider "place". The statement

```
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q618123 .
```

will give you all the instances of "geographical objects" and its subclasses which might be a good starting point to explore.

Comment: Thanks Tom!  Unfortunately, I seem to be timing out with this.  (Server error: Unexpected end of JSON input).  Any clever ways to get around this limitation?